# Bean Scope("Request") does not work

Tags: java, spring, annotations, scope, request

I am trying to use Spring Scoped Beans with `@Scope("Request")`. According to the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other), If one is using the ServletDispatcher, no other setup is required.

Even though I marked some of the beans as `@Scope("Request")` I am still getting for every request the same bean objects, which means that I am getting the default Singleton behavior.

In the code below I am trying to make the `statusService` have the scope request.

The controller code:

```
@Controller
public class CrawlerController {
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private ScrappingService scrappingService;
    @Autowired
    private RepositoryService repositoryService;
    @Autowired
    private StatusService statusService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "candleAndVolume";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return statusService.getStatus();
    }
```

Status Service:

```
@Scope (value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public class StatusService {
    String status;

    public String getStatus(){
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status){
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Web.xml - Just in case it is needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- listener to load the root application context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>health</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/health.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>health</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/health</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Application Context:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean name="scrapper" class="net.crawler.service.scrap.DefaultScrapperImpl"/>

    <bean name="statusService" class="net.crawler.service.StatusService"/>

    <bean name="scrappingService" class="net.crawler.service.scrap.ScrappingService"/>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/app.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="gmailDefaultSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${app.mail.host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${app.mail.port}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${app.mail.userName}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${app.mail.password}"/>

        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean name="pendingPages" class="net.crawler.general.PendingPages"/>

    <bean id="utils" class="net.crawler.general.Utils">
        <property name="exporterMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="CrawlerExporter" value-ref="crawlerExporter"/>
                <entry key="CsvMailExporter" value-ref="csvMailExporter"/>
                <entry key="SendCustomMailExporter" value-ref="sendCustomMailExporter"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="crawlerExporter" class="net.crawler.service.export.CrawlerExporter"/>

    <bean name="csvMailExporter" class="net.crawler.service.export.CsvMailExporter">
        <property name="sendTo" value="${app.mail.recipient}"/>
        <property name="sender" ref="gmailDefaultSender"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="sendCustomMailExporter" class="net.crawler.service.export.SendCustomMailExporter">
        <property name="sendTo" value="${app.mail.recipient}"/>
        <property name="sender" ref="gmailDefaultSender"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you post `applicationContext.xml` as well?

Comment: How do you define `StatusService` as a bean? Using annotations or XML or `@Configuration`?

Comment: StatusService is defined in the applicationContext and wired to the controller

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable

```
<aop:scoped-proxy/>
```

so that you get a proxy instead of the bean directly. Check out the [scoped beans as dependencies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) section in the documentation.